# Is it possible to view google apps smtp logs?

Tags: g-suite

I run a mail server that uses icewarp merak and I am unable to send to my google apps standard account. The google apps account has been in use for more than a year with no problems. Viewing the logs on the merak server, I see that the message was accepted for delivery. However, I dont receive the email (not in spam folder either) and I never get an error returned. How can I troubleshoot an issue like this?

Comment: I cannot comment yet, so I will have to do a blind shot. Have you checked that the merak server is doing the delivery to Google? It could happen that it is delivering the message to another smtp server, not to Google. You could get better help if you paste the log lines.

Comment: You see that the message was accepted for delivery by who? By your server running merak, or by a google mail server? Can you edit the question and post the relevant logs that you see?

Answer (score 2):

**You** can't see Google's SMTP logs. Google can.

Comment: This is no longer true, Google Apps admins can now view SMTP logs, see https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578